# Css is not working after deployment of a JavaFX app in Eclipse

Tags: css, eclipse, deployment, javafx

If I deploy a JavaFX app from Eclipse then it won't load the CSS file for some reason, though the app works as expected inside Eclipse.

Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

 Stage primaryStage;

 @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

    showMain();
}

public void showMain(){
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("Mainwindow.fxml"));
        AnchorPane ap = loader.load();
        ap.getStylesheets().add(Main.class.getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

        Scene scene = new Scene(ap);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The css is:

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

.button{
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}
```

The fxml:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="381.0" prefWidth="446.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="14.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

In the build.xml I just set the obligatory things. I don't convert the `css` into `bss`. I sign it and that's all.

The build.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project name="JavaFXTester6_Web" default="do-deploy" basedir="."  xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
     <target name="init-fx-tasks">
        <path id="fxant">
            <filelist>
                <file name="${java.home}\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
                <file name="${java.home}\lib\jfxrt.jar"/>
            </filelist>
        </path>

        <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"      
        uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
        classpathref="fxant"/>
     </target>
<target name="setup-staging-area">
    <delete dir="externalLibs" />
    <delete dir="project" />
    <delete dir="projectRefs" />

    <mkdir dir="externalLibs" />


    <mkdir dir="project" />
    <copy todir="project">
        <fileset dir="/home/zooey/LinuxEclipse/linuxWorkspace/JavaFXTester6_Web">
            <include name="src/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <mkdir dir="projectRefs" />
</target>
<target name='do-compile'>
    <delete dir="build" />
    <mkdir dir="build/src" />
    <mkdir dir="build/libs" />
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />

    <!-- Copy project-libs references -->
    <copy todir="build/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <!-- Copy project references -->

    <!-- Copy project sources itself -->
    <copy todir="build/src">
        <fileset dir="project/src">
            <include name="**/*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <javac includeantruntime="false" source="1.8" target="1.8" srcdir="build/src" destdir="build/classes" encoding="UTF-8">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="build/libs">
                <include name="*"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>

    <!-- Copy over none Java-Files -->
    <copy todir="build/classes">
    <fileset dir="project/src">
        <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
    </copy>


</target>
<target name="do-deploy" depends="setup-staging-area, do-compile, init-fx-tasks">
    <delete file="dist"/>
    <delete file="deploy" />

    <mkdir dir="dist" />
    <mkdir dir="dist/libs" />

    <copy todir="dist/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="*" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>


    <fx:resources id="appRes">
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="JavaFXTester6_Web.jar"/>
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/*"/>
    </fx:resources> 

    <fx:application id="fxApplication"
        name="Test"
        mainClass="application.Main"
    />

    <mkdir dir="build/classes/META-INF" />



    <fx:jar destfile="dist/JavaFXTester6_Web.jar">
        <fx:application refid="fxApplication"/>
        <fileset dir="build/classes">
        </fileset>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="ZA"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="Test"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="1.0"/>
            <attribute name="JavaFX-Feature-Proxy" value="None"/>
        </manifest>
    </fx:jar>
    <fx:signjar //intentionally removed >
    <fileset dir='dist'>
            <include name='**/*.jar' />
        </fileset>
    </fx:signjar>
    <mkdir dir="deploy" />
    <!-- Need to use ${basedir} because somehow the ant task is calculating the directory differently -->
    <fx:deploy
        embedJNLP="false"
        extension="false"
        width="400" height="400" 
        includeDT="false"
        offlineAllowed="true"
        outdir="${basedir}/deploy"
        outfile="JavaFXTester6_Web" 
        placeholderref="webtest" 
        placeholderid="webtest" 
        updatemode="background" >

        <fx:info title="JavaFXTester6_Web" vendor="ZA"/>
        <fx:application refId="fxApplication"/>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>
        <fx:permissions elevated="true"/>
    </fx:deploy>


</target>
```

The file system I get after running the build.xml:

[image: file system]

The same in my file browser:

[image: file system 2]

I couldn't fin any solutions, everybody mentions the conversion from css to bss, but I tried both (so with `Main.class.getResource(style.bss)...` too) and no solution. I have unfortunately no more ideas. Can you help? Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly is your `.class` and `.css` file present inside `build/classes` directory?

Comment: hi, they are in: workspace/JavaFXTester6_Web/build/build/classes/application - here is the .class the .fxml and the .css
JavaFXTester6_Web is the projects name.

Comment: If all the three files are located in the same package, it should get loaded. Can you add a snapshot of the directory structure? (I know, adding a "/path-to-your-css" will solve your issue, but I am just curious about the structure.)

Comment: they are really in one folder, please see the edited post

Comment: To make it work use `Main.class.getResource("/application/style.css")`.

Comment: Btw, why do you have `build` directory twice?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't want to do it, unfortunately it is still not applying the CSS outside of Eclipse. I don't know why is the build folder duplicated. It is generated so by the `build.fxbuild` when I press build and run. If I just press build, then I get the build folder with the build.xml in it. When I run it then it creates the sub folders as you see again. So there is no difference between build & build and run. Every setting is default, I only fill in the obligatory fields marked with *s.

Comment: Now I tried to copy the content of the second build folder to its parent folder and then delete the second build folder, but with no success.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75030/discussion-between-itachiuchiha-and-user3435407).

Comment: Ok, the duplicate issue is solved, it was because I thought build should be the build directory, I corrected it, now I have just one build folder, but it is still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because of the `@CHARSET "UTF-8";` in your css file.

JavaFX cannot parse it and will throw a parse exception.

Remove the CHARSET declaration from the css and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It all works fine in Eclipse but when I compile and run the jar, the CSS is ignored. Extracting the complied jar shows the CSS file and images in the same folder as the Java class files.

FXML

```
<stylesheets>
  <URL value="@Style.css" />
</stylesheets>
```

CSS

```
-fx-background-image: url("background.jpg");
```

Okay, I figured it out. The CSS file and the image file need to be in the root directory of the jar. In Eclipse the CSS file and image files are in the package with the Java files, but when you compile they need to go in the src folder outside of the package.

You do not need the line;

Java

```
ap.getStylesheets().add(Main.class.getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
```

The FXML file should tell the program where to find the CSS file, and the CSS file tells the program where to find images.